# What´s the best/practical way to do trees with pstricks pictures in nodes?, with PSTricks, Pst-node

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, pstricks-add

I have test that psmatrix is a good way to do diagrams, but ... to do diagrams where the nodes is not displayed as a "perfect matrix/table".

What is the recommended way to do any similar to, with ps pictures in the nodes?, with fully liberty for place where I want the center of the node.
[image]

Code example with psmatrix:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-blur,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}
\definecolor{azultenue}{RGB}{65,170,193}
\definecolor{rojotenue}{RGB}{192,2,3}
\definecolor{naranjatenue}{RGB}{241,101,35}
\definecolor{verdetenue}{RGB}{144,169,61}
\definecolor{gris135}{RGB}{135,135,135}

\begin{document}

\vspace{2.1cm}
 \begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\resizebox{10cm}{!}{

\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm,nodesep=0.12cm}
%
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 1cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip 1cm}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.2, colsep=5.2]% defines the distance between two frames
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
&
&
\\[2.5cm]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 [name=Inicio]
 \psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%
 \rput(0,1.5){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=azultenue]{p1}{\textcolor{black}{$p_1$}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
&[name=Conjunto]
\psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
&[name=EM]
\psframegray(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
\end{psmatrix}
%
{\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos = 0.4,nodesep=2.6cm}
\ncline{Inicio}{Conjunto}
\ncline{Conjunto}{EM}
}

}
%\vspace{3.85cm}
\vspace{2.85cm}
\caption{Esquema $(1 + \lambda)$}\label{1maslambda-ilustracion}
\end{figure}

\vspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `pst-tree`?

Comment: @Bernard, no necessarily. In any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also possible to place the frames with `\rput`. `showgrid=true` enables the grid for the coordinates and `showgrid=false` hide it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pst-blur,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\myFrameNode#1(#2){\rput(#2){\rnode{#1}{%
  \psframe[framearc=0.2,shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,shadow,
           fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray](-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\resizebox{10cm}{!}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](17,6)
\myFrameNode{Inicio}(3,3)%
\myFrameNode{Conjunto}(9,3)%
\myFrameNode{EM}(15,3)
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=2.6cm}%
\ncline{Inicio}{Conjunto}%
\ncline{Conjunto}{EM}%
\end{pspicture}%
}
\caption{Esquema $(1 + \lambda)$}\label{1maslambda-ilustracion}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\psscalebox{0.6}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](13,12)
\myFrameNode{Inicio}(3,5)%
\myFrameNode{Conjunto}(10,9)%
\myFrameNode{EM}(10,2.5)%
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=2.6cm}%
\ncline{Inicio}{Conjunto}%
\ncline{Conjunto}{EM}%
\ncline{Inicio}{EM}%
\end{pspicture}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer! I need to learn more about \def \...#1....#2 ....#2....#1. Any suggestion for that purpose?.

Comment: look into one of the PSTricks packages or http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/texbytopic, also available as a book from DANTE: http://www.dante.de/index/Literatur/tbt.html